# VBO - Cube Offsets

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, cube

I have some code that is supposed to create a new VBO and fill it with cubes that I created using offsets instead of `glTranslate`. I have a cubeVBO class that creates a new cube with offsets, but for some reason that code is only being called once. It also seems like culling isn't working correctly because the faces of the cube disappear when I'm right in front of them. Here's the class:

```
public class CubeVBO {

public int vboVHandle;
int offset = Block.size;
int count = 0;
public FloatBuffer vertices;

public CubeVBO(float x, float z, float y){
    vertices = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 4 * 6);
    vertices.put(new float[] {
            x + offset, y + offset, z, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z,
            x - offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y - offset, z - Block.size, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z - Block.size, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z, 
            x + offset, y - offset, z, 
            x + offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y - offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y - offset, z, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z, 
            x + offset, y + offset, z, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x - offset, y + offset, z, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z, 
            x - offset, y - offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y + offset, z, 
            x + offset, y + offset, z - Block.size, 
            x + offset, y - offset,
            z - Block.size, x + offset, y - offset, z });
    vertices.flip();

    vboVHandle = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

}
And I use it in this class:

```
public class BaseChunk {

// x - left/right y - up/down y - forward/backward

VBO vbo;
CubeVBO vertexVBO;

public static final int CHUNK_X = 16;
public static final int CHUNK_Y = 16;
public static final int CHUNK_Z = 16;

public boolean rebuild = false;

FloatBuffer blockPositionData;
FloatBuffer vertexColorData;

private Block[][][] blocks;
private int vboBlockData;

public BaseChunk() {

    blocks = new Block[CHUNK_X][CHUNK_Z][CHUNK_Y];
    blockPositionData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer((CHUNK_X * CHUNK_Z * CHUNK_Y) * 6 * 12);

    for (int xx = 0; xx < CHUNK_X; xx++) {
        for (int zz = 0; zz < CHUNK_Z; zz++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < CHUNK_Y; yy++) {
                blocks[xx][zz][yy] = Block.Grass;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void rebuildChunk(int id) {
    if (rebuild) {

    }
}

public void makeChunk(){
    for(int x = 0; x <= 16; x++){
        for(int z = 0; z <= 16; z++){
            for(int y = 0; y <= 16; y++){
                vertexVBO = new CubeVBO((float) 16 + x, (float) 16 + z, (float) 16 + y);
            }
        }
    }

    vboBlockData = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboBlockData);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, blockPositionData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void render() {
    vbo = new VBO();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBO.vboVHandle);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo.vboCHandle);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
                glPushMatrix();
                //glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
                glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
                glPopMatrix();
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

Are my offsets incorrect? Or is my VBO code incorrect?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problems is that in makeChunk() you are creating lots of CubeVBO's, but you are assigning them all to the same variable, so when the method ends, only the last one you created is referenced by vertexVBO. In render(), you are binding and drawing that final CubeVBO.

You need to create one big VBO that contains the vertices for all cubes and bind and draw that. Don't forget to update the count parameter for glDrawArrays.